# document and jQuery object not found in javaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern, self-executing-function

I've been having a problem with the below custom function.
I'm trying to access both the jQuery and document object by passing it to the function itself but it doesn't work.
I don't understand what is wrong with it.
Can you please help?

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

var MyApp = (function(window,document,$){


  //private method not returned
  var _checkNumbers = function () {

  };

  var _checkSpecialChars = function () {

  };

  var _checkWordCount = function () {

  };

  var _checkRemainingChars = function () {
    var myField = document.getElementById("textarea-content");
    console.log("id", myField);

  };

  var stringValidation = function () {
     _checkRemainingChars();
      console.log("it works");

  };

  return {
      stringValidation: stringValidation
  };

})(window,document,jQuery);

MyApp.stringValidation();
```

Comment: [Works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ee1wzndw/) as long as jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Do you mean if jQuery library is being loaded in the HTML file? yes it is. The strange thing is that 'document' doesn't work either.

Comment: @Beppe _"The strange thing is that 'document' doesn't work either."_ https://jsfiddle.net/ee1wzndw/1/

Comment: Make sure that you are loading jQuery before you try to pass it to the function. Testing your script throws no errors once jQuery is loaded.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm importing both the JS and jQuery files in the HTML. Am I missing something in the script above? Shall I add something to make jQuery and document available before passing them to the function?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? Is `<script>` which loads jQuery before `<script>` that defines `MyApp` ?

Answer (score 0):

This the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Paragraph Tab List App</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Internet Explorer 8 or older versions doesn't support CSS3 media queries. I enable it by importing css3-mediaqueries.js Javascript file. -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->  

<!-- importing jquery library -->
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>

  <!-- importing custom script file -->
  <script src="./js/function.js" ></script> 

<!-- importing custom css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"/>

</head> 
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">
      <h1 class="main-heading"> Paragraph parser</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="main">

      <form class="form" action="index.html" method="post">
        <label for="textarea-content">Insert the paragraph to be parsed:</label>
        <textarea class="form__textarea" id="textarea-content" name="textarea-content" placeholder="Please enter a paragraph..."></textarea>
        <div class="form__limit-message">(Maximum characters: 500)</div>
        <button class="form__button btn--blue btn--medium">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```